# Android NDK application: could not load library "libcrystax.so"

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm developing Android NDK application with Crystax NDK.
I've copied both my executable and libcrystax.so to device:

```
adb push ./libs/armeabi/libcrystax.so /mnt/libcrystax.so
adb push ./libs/armeabi/cpp_test /mnt/cpp_test
```

And when I simply run executable in adb shell it returns:

```
$ ./cpp_test
```

`soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libcrystax.so" needed by "./cpp_test"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "libcrystax.so" not foundCANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE`

So the question is where to put libcrystax.so?

Comment: This seems related: http://serverfault.com/questions/279068/cant-find-so-in-the-same-directory-as-the-executable

Comment: @Michael, Thank you it fixed the problem!